# Call constructor as a function in C#

Tags: c#, lambda

Is there a way in C# to reference a class constructor as a standard function? The reason is that Visual Studio complains about modifying functions with lambdas in them, and often its a simple select statement.

For example `var ItemColors = selectedColors.Select (x => new SolidColorBrush(x));`, where selectedColors is just an `IEnumerable<System.Windows.Media.Color>`.

Technically speaking, shouldn't the lambda be redundant? select takes a function accepting a type T and returning type U. The solid color brush takes (the correct) type T here and returns a U. Only I see no way to do this in C#. In F#  it would be something like `let ItemColors = map selectedColors (new SolidColorBrush)`.

TL;DR: I guess I'm looking for the valid form of `var ItemColors = selectedColors.select (new SolidColorBrush)` which doens't require a lamba. Is this possible in C# or does the language have no way to express this construct?

Comment: relevant issue opened
https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2846

Comment: This question was asked again, six years later, here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44127501/773113 I would not call that question a duplicate of this one, because that question has been formulated in a more direct, pertinent, and understandable way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No you cannot reference a C# constructor as a method group and pass it as a delegate parameter.  The best way to do so is via the lambda syntax in your question.

Answer (score 7):

You could lay out a formal method:

```
private static SolidColorBrush Transform(Color color)
{
    return new SolidColorBrush(color);
}
```

Then you can use `Select` like this:

```
var ItemColors = selectedColors.Select(Transform);
```

Comment: +1, This is a construction pattern I have grown to like quite a lot lately, especially for faux-immutability, and in base classes which call methods on their implementors from the static Create().

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand you correctly. But are you talking about a `factory`?

This way you can pass a value to the factory and it will create an instance for you.

```
SolidColorBrush brush = ColorBrushFactory.BrushFrom(color);
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: He's trying to create a Delegate instance from a normal ctor.