# C# Method-reference of constructor

Tags: c#, constructor, reference, delegates

In C# I can have references of methods and static methods. Can I also get the reference of a classes constructor?

In Java I can say `Supplier<MyClass> createMyClass = MyClass::new` (instead of the longer lambda syntax). 
In C# I only know the notation `Func<MyClass> createMyClass = () => MyClass()`. But I think the Java way with the constructor reference is better readable.

And I don't want to make a static `CreateMyClass` function. I really want the constructor.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, there's no equivalent of method group conversions for constructors, or properties, indexers or operators.

It's an entirely reasonable idea, but it isn't in C# at the moment. It *is*, however, tracked as part of a [feature request in the C# design repo](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/84) - so you may want to subscribe to that issue.