# LINQ Short constructor as action

Tags: c#, linq

With linq i can create a query like this

```
XElement.Elements("...").Select(x=> useX(x));
```

now as x creates only a wrapper Action and useX's parameter is XElement you can use it like this aswell:

```
XElement.Elements("...").Select(useX);
```

However when i have a type that has a constructor with a matching type i.e. MyClass(XElement element) i have to use:

```
XElement.Elements("...").Select(x=> new MyClass(x));
```

My question: Is there any way to shorten the construction of an object in a way like above but with a constructor? I imagined something like this:

```
XElement.Elements("...").Select(MyClass);
```

Comment: Your class might have different overloaded constructors, and presence of `x` as a lambda parameter is not enough for compiler to infer  which ctor to use: for example, you might want to use default one of `MyClass`, regardless if there is `x` or not.

Comment: You can have multiple overloads of a method too, so not really an argument @Tigran

Comment: @PatrickHofman: not sure what multiple overloaded methods have to do with all of this. my point is that in this scenario you have to specify concrete ctor to use, even in case when compiler is able to some degree determine which ctor to use on its own. you have to be explicit.

Comment: But how does `.Select(useX)` know which method to call? It is just a matter of method resolution, and constructors could go the same way @Tigran

Comment: This isn't quite a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35420610/passing-a-method-to-a-linq-query, but the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/35422304/400547 explains why the answer to this is "no".

Comment: Incidentally, there are times where explicitly defining the action has a slight performance (in both time taken and memory used) advantage over passing in the method group, with current compiler implementations; the action will be cached in many cases, but the method group will not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there any way to shorten the construction of an object in a way like above but with a constructor

Short answer: No, there is not.

Longer "answer" (not actually an answer, more a workaround if you want it):

You can add a static construction method to `MyClass`:

```
public class MyClass
{
   public MyClass(XElement elem) 
   {
       // your constructor logic
   }

   public static MyClass Create(XElement elem)
   {
      return new MyClass(elem);
   }
}
```

and use that

```
XElement.Elements("...").Select(MyClass.Create);
```

But whether it's worth it is up to you! (Personal opinion: It's not worth it, just stick with `new MyClass(x)`)

Comment: That is a workaround, not an answer to the question.

Comment: @PatrickHofman *everything* is a workaround for the problem that computers dont speak english :)

Comment: I can't argue that.

Comment: This answers the question, regardless of how someone describes it.

Comment: Well, it isn't bad, but it doesn't answer the question "Is there any way to shorten the construction of an object in a way like above but with a constructor?".

Comment: I actually agree with @PatrickHofman so ive updated my answer appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Sad its not possible, maybe they should implement it :) The Create method workaround will not apply for my application though it looks sweet and reminds me of some java syntax.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't shorten a call to a constructor inside a lambda expression. The problem is that a constructor is called from an operation with new `new` operator.

You are stuck with `.Select(x=> new MyClass(x))`. Of course, you can make a factory method to call instead, but that is more like a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the syntax that accepts a *method-group* only works, if the actually delegate to be used can clearly be inferred from the usage. E.g. a method returning an int and expecting one, that has no further overloads, can also be used like this:

```
Select(myMethod);
```

However if there are overloads, you can´t do this, as it´s unclear which of them you mean.

For constructors it´s a bit different. There´s no way on referencing it using a *method-group*. `MyClass` isn´t a valid method-group for `new MyClass()`.

So in short: [you can´t reference a constructor using a method-group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44127501/c-sharp-method-reference-of-constructor).